# Flash Lite 1.1 Read File?

Tags: text-files, flashlite, readfile

Is it possible to read a simple text file (stored on the mobile phone) with Flash Lite 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `LoadVariablesNum("variables.txt", 0)` and its worked.